# Java abstract class "instance variables"

Tags: java, abstract-class

I don't know if my mind just fools me or this is really not working.

I need different type of Logging-classes so I created a abstract-class, the only definition that all classes will have the same is the way the writeToLog is handled:

```
public abstract class LoggerTemplate {

    protected String filename ="log/";
    protected File logfile;

    protected FileWriter fw;

    public void writeToLog(String message) {
        if(fw != null) {
            try {
                message = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-hh:mm").format(new Date()) + " " + message;
                fw.write(message);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The concrete sub-classes will implement rest of the logic in their constructor, ie one of them:

```
public class JitterBufferLogger extends LoggerTemplate {

    public JitterBufferLogger() {
        super();
        filename += new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddMMhhmm'.log'").format(new Date());

        if(!new File("log/").exists())
            new File("log").mkdir();


        logfile = new File(filename);
        try {
            logfile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(logfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I debug I can see that when calling the writeToLog for a specific logger, it jumps into the LoggerTemplate method, and therefore fw and logfile are null. So it's not working.

Isn't it supposed to work or do I just mess something a bit up and should go into weekend ;-)

Comment: This "should" work (regarding assignment of super-classes member variables). Did you debug into the constructor of `JitterBufferLogger`? Probably stdout goes to an unexpected location and you missed the stacktraces. Also, 'log/.20122012.log' (the slash) is not a valid filename - see logfile.createNewFile(filename).

Comment: Did you check for the stack trace on opening the file writer? Per @MartinK's comment, the invalid file name is probably your issue.

Comment: Consider having a `File parentDir` in your base class and have the base class constructor populate it and create the dir. Then in the concrete class do `new File(super.parentDir, fileName)` or `super.parentDir.createNewFile(fileName)`

Comment: new ErrorLogger().writeToLog("test my derp skills"); But the main problem just seemed that fw did not write properly to the file. I capsulated it with a printwriter and it is working as expected. Don't know what messed my brain but somehow something did..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, it is normal, that the debugger stepped into the `LoggerTemplate` class upon entering the `writeToLog()` method. What is strange that the attributes in the base class have `null` values.

I have tested your code with the following short test program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoggerTemplate lt = new JitterBufferLogger();
        lt.writeToLog("Hello");
    }
}
```

After adding `fw.flush()` to the `LoggerTemplate.writeToLog()` method just after the `fw.write()` call, it worked for me, the log file had been created and it contained the log message.

Maybe the `new File("log").mkdir()` or some other calls throw an exception which you cannot see, because *stderr* had been redirected somewhere.

Comment: yap, the stepp to LoggerTemplate must be there, how else should it work. Maybe the flush just failed, I will update my post with the new wrapping with PrintWriter which now works.

Answer (score 1):

So what may be missing?
- filewriter flushing could have helped.
- I can't reproduce the null values with the original code, don't know what happened.
- but as everybody, including me, said: it should work and it does.

Why was nothing in the logfile?
- maybe the flush of fw was missing..

anyhow I wrapped it with a Printwriter:

```
public abstract class LoggerTemplate {

    protected String filename ="log/";
    protected File logfile;

    protected PrintWriter pw;

    public void writeToLog(String message) {
            try {
                pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(logfile,true));
                message = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-hh:mm").format(new Date()) + " " + message + "\n";
                pw.write(message);
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

and now it's working like it should and was expected to be.
Note that the fw instantiation in the concrete sub-classes is not needed anymore.